# Filter data on firebase using Searchview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` of Firebase-UI. The listing is working properly, but I'm not able to implement the filter in SearchView.

My users database:
**Firebase Users**

[image]

```
private DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

   UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(
       User.class,
       R.layout.user,
       UserAdapter.UserViewHolder.class,
       reference
   );

   recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);

}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity, menu);

     MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
     searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);        
 }

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    // ???
    return true;
}
```

**Edited**

I tried this code on onQueryTextSubmit, the filter worked but with strange behavior.

```
UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(
       User.class,
       R.layout.user,
       UserAdapter.UserViewHolder.class,
       reference.orderByChild("name").startAt(newText.toUpperCase());
 );
recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
return true;
```

Is there any way to update the Query of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter? userAdapter.updateQuery() or something like that?

**Note**

The FirebaseUI adapters for Android don't yet have support for client-side filtering. The request to add this is tracked in [this Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15).

Comment: I think you have to write your own adapter.

Comment: what problem you are facing, did you solve this problem? if yes, plz update and answer it. thanx in advance

Comment: @RuchaBhatt Bhatt, did you figured out ?

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. not yet..